# Can you configure NO_PROXY in NPM?

Tags: npm, npm-install

When using a private npm repository, I need the ability to send some requests through a proxy server and others direct to the server.

Usually, setting the environment variables HTTP_PROXY, HTTPS_PROXY, and NO_PROXY resolve this.

I understand npm does not have a command-line option for no_proxy, but I haven't been able to get npm to respect the NO_PROXY environment variable: After setting the environment variables above, npm install times out when downloading external libraries (which require to be downloaded through the corporate proxy)

My ~/.npmrc file has the following:

registry=http://[internal_npm_registry]

email=[email]

I am running npm version 3.10.10. Has anyone had the same need and resolved it?

Comment: I ran  into the same issue.  NPM is not respecting NO_PROXY env var on Windows 10 with npm version 3.10.10.

Comment: i have the same problem with 3.10.3. I searched the configuration help for npm 3.10.3 we're using and there's no 'noproxy' option as there is for newer versions. This somehow tells me that they don't support noproxy/no_proxy/NO_PROXY/no-proxy configuration in their .npmrc files either .. am I mistaken ? 

for version 5.4.2 (the other version we're using) there's only the proxy and https-proxy option for the config .. 

The simplest way i solved building was to remove the .npmrc project file and use the global mesos cloud npm configuration .

Answer (score 13):

I had the same problem at work: we have a private Nexus npm repository where we host some custom modules and we needed npm to not use the proxy when requesting these packages.

The only reliable solution I found for Windows was by setting the environment variables you listed and actually removing all proxy values from npm (set `proxy`, `https-proxy` and `https_proxy` all to `null` in your `.npmrc` file).

So for example, the `.npmrc` file in the project root looks like this:

```
strict-ssl=false
ca=null
registry=http://my-nexus-repo.com/repository/npm-packages/
my-custom-registry-on-nexus:registry=http://my-nexus-repo.com/repository/hosted-npm-packages/
https_proxy=null
https-proxy=null
proxy=null
```

Sticking with the example above, your `no_proxy` environment variable would look something like:

`my-nexus-repo.com,localhost`

Doing this allowed us to seamlessly install all npm packages (even tricky ones like `node-sass` that download tarballs outside of npm).

Answer (score 5):

With `npm 5.3.0 / node 8.4.0`, the `NO_PROXY` environment variable works as a charm !

Comment: Thanks, it also works fine in Linux npm 6.1.0 / node 10.3.0